# Why isn't the most specific method called based on type of parameter

Tags: c#, oop, polymorphism, overloading

Total OO noob question here. I have these two methods in a class

```
private void StoreSessionSpecific(LateSession dbSession, SessionViewModel session)
{
    session.LateSessionViewModel.Guidelines = dbSession.Guidelines.ToList();
}

private void StoreSessionSpecific(Session dbSession, SessionViewModel session )
{
        // nothing to do yet...
}
```

And when I call StoreSessionSpecific with dbSession being of type LateSession (LateSession inherits Session)

```
var dbSession = new LateSession();
StoreSessionSpecific(dbSession, session);
```

I expected the top one to be called. Since dbSession is of type LateSession.

@Paolo Tedesco This is how the classes are defined.

```
public class Session
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SessionTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual SessionType SessionType { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    // Session duration in minutes
    // public int SessionDuration { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }

}

public class LateSession : Session
{


    public int MaxCriticalIncidentsPerUser { get; set; }
    public int MaxResultCriticalIncidents { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Guideline> Guidelines { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're typing as 'var' rather than 'LateSession'?

Comment: @acron, what would be the reason not to type `var`?

Comment: @detunized, it's just my opinion that `var` is lazy, especially then you're allocating a specific type to it like Saab is. Why *wouldn't* you define as `LateSession`? In fact, is this whole problem not a testament against using `var`?

Comment: `var` != `dynamic` if that's your reason against using it. It's a programmer's shortcut. The compiler still enforces strong typing and will complain if it can't determine the actual type.

Comment: @Yuck, I understand that, but in this case it's apparently getting the type *wrong*, which is just as bad.

Comment: `var` is beautiful, not just lazy.  Lazy too, but in a good way.  Especially in contexts like this one.  It allows to keep things DRY and less verbose.  There's no need to repeat the type information twice on the same line.

Comment: @acron Because it's obvious from the statement that he's creating a LateSession. It makes for cleaner, easier to read, code.

Comment: @acron, using var here is totally equivalent to using the full type name, it's just sintactic sugar...

Comment: In this example, it's lazy. If you know the type and it's not going to change, there's no excuse not to type it properly. And you can't claim "It's obvious" when the compiler is getting it wrong!

Comment: @acron, I seriously doubt it gets the type wrong.  There must be something else going on.

Comment: @acron The problem has nothing to do with var or LateSession, in this case the code doesn't work because the language goes with whichever method it finds first that matches the signature, without going on to check if there's a "better" match.

Comment: Well, perhaps, but from what we're given it's a sound assumption to make and Angel O'Sphere agrees with me. In any situation, if I new the type I would specify it - why leave it to chance?

Comment: @acron: leave it to chance??? do you really believe that the behavior of the compiled code is random??? try to make a working, full example that supports your theory, you will not succeed.

Comment: @acron, there's no rolling dice here.  It's pretty well defined what `var` means in this context.

Comment: Are you serious? This entire problem pivots around the fact that it's picking the WRONG function and this is because he's typing as `var`. My 2 pence was not to use `var`, but to type it specifically. That is a **valid** solution to this problem.

Comment: @Michail, the language does *not* go with the method it finds first that matches the arguments.

Comment: @acron, have you actually tried that what you're saying?  Replacing `var` here with `LateSession` will not change a thing.  Chances are that the problem is somewhere else.  Take a look at the answers below.

Comment: Just to be a bit more clear. I put "var" in the above code because I didn't want to copy paste all of my code. Sorry for that.
This is how I retrieve dbSession: 

Session dbSession = context.Sessions.Single(x => x.ID == id);

Which returns an ...proxy->LateSession->Session object when I check it at runtime in the debugger.

Comment: @Saab, in this case, the omitted code is the important piece. See Angel O'Sphere's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, your assumption is plausible and there are languages where it had worked like you thought.

So does your code look like this:

```
Session s = new LateSession(); // the compiler only "knows" that s is of type Session
StoreSessionSpecific(s);
```

or does it look like this:

```
LateSession ls = new LateSession(); // the compiler knows that ls is in fact a LateSession
StoreSessionSpecific(ls);
```

In the first example the compiler prettends not to know what the actual type of "s" is and hard codes the invocation of the method with the Session argument.
In the second example likewise the compiler generates a hard coded call to the other method.

In other languages the method call is "dynamic", that means during runtime the actuall types are considered. Methods that are polymorphic on their arguments are called "multimethods" (They are not only polymorphic on the class they are defined in but also on the arguments, hence "multi")
(Edit: fixed typos)

Comment: A nice explanation, I never knew this. Further Googling revealed that neither C#, nor Java allow multiple dispatch, but Lisp and Python do.

Comment: But actually, in this case, things **should** work as expected, as the type is known at compile time, and the correct overload should be invoked. There's probably some other problem which is not evident from the example being shown...

Comment: The type is not "really" known at compile time. Consider the variabel comming via a parameter. I only placed the "new" there that we as readers know what is going on ;D

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is somewhere else in your code. If you try this example, things work as expected:

```
class Base { 
}

class Derived : Base { 
}

class Something {
    private void DoSomething(Base b) {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething - Base");
    }
    private void DoSomething(Derived d) {
        Console.WriteLine("DoSomething - Derived");
    }
    public void Test() {
        var d = new Derived();
        DoSomething(d);
    }
}

static class Program {
    static void Main(params string[] args) {
        Something something = new Something();
        something.Test();
    }
}
```

Could you post a complete example? maybe there's a problem with the class definitions...

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for not knowing the specifics of *why* this happens, but I have an idea on how to work around it.

Try loosing the `(LateSession, SessionViewModel)` overload, and account for LateSession in the `(Session, SessionViewModel)` overload like:

```
private void StoreSessionSpecific(Session dbSession, SessionViewModel session )
{
   if (dbSession is LateSession) { 
      // handle as LateSession
   } else { 
      // handle as base-class Session
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Angel O'Sphere said, C# doesn't have multiple dispatch however you can implement double dispatch using Visitor Pattern.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of `dbSession` after that assignment?  I would assume it is what you expect, but it could be a `Session`.

Separately, do you really need to overload this method with both a child and parent class?  It seems like a strange case where you would need both, and will likely lead to confusion.

Comment: I put that there just as an illustration. So dbSession is of type LateSession. Runtime in my code I see that dbSession is of type LateSession, and the baseclass is Session.
I wanna do it this this way so I have different behaviour for different types. Otherwise I'll resort to the uber nasty switch.